# Symfony - Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, twig

i am having troubles with datetime attribute in my class.

Next code is in my twig template.

```
<div class="process-photo"><img src="{{ photo.getPhotoUrl }}" /></div>
```

This is the getPhotoUrl method

```
 public function getPhotoUrl()
    {
        return '/web/uploads/photos/'.$this->getUserId().'/'.$this->getPhotoUploadDate().'/'.$this->getName();
    }
```

This is the getPhotoUploadDate method

```
public function getPhotoUploadDate() {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->creationDate));
    }
```

I am getting next error - Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

If i try this way

```
public function getPhotoUrl()
    {
        return '/web/uploads/photos/'.$this->getUserId().'/'.$this->creationDate.'/'.$this->getName();
    }
```

I am getting next error - Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

what i am doing wrong??

Comment: The error message `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string` is all the information you need. `$this->creationDate` is an DateTime object, so instead of `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->creationDate))` you could easily `$this->creationDate->format('Y-m-d')`. Why would you create a date from a date you already have?

Comment: yes that worked! thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, I answered your question, you can accept it if my solution worked.

Answer (score 4):

The error message

> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

is all the information you need.

`$this->creationDate` is an DateTime object, it already contains the Date information.

So instead of `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->creationDate))` you could easily `$this->creationDate->format('Y-m-d')`.

You're trying to create a new Datestring from another datestring and instead of giving a datestring you're giving the `DateTime` Object.